# CSS animation to fade in and out at different rates with a pause

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to get a badge i've design to fade in and out, but I am lacking some understanding of css animations. What I would like is is a 2s fade in, a 10 second pause, and a 2s fade out.

Right now I have a 2s fade in and fade out. But what would be the next part of this?

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864011/css-animation-fade-in-pause-fade-out), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125705/css-how-to-make-an-element-fade-in-and-then-fade-out), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48175922/css-animation-fade-in-fade-out-opacity-on-automated-slideshow), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-a-fade-in-effect-on-page-load), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907079/css3-transition-fade-out-effect), [and here](https://medium.com/cloud-native-the-gathering/how-to-use-css-to-fade-in-and-fade-out-html-text-and-pictures-f45c11364f08) but nothing really covers exactly what i'm looking for, and any modifications i've made have screwed everything up. Is this even possible in pure css?

```
  .fadeInAndOut {
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 2s linear forwards;
    animation: fadeinout 2s linear forwards;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
    0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
    50% { opacity: 1; }
  }

  @keyframes fadeinout {
    0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
    50% { opacity: 1; }
  }
```

I have also tried something more complex, but theres a lot of flickering involved, and it seems to be in a loop as well [based off this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864011/css-animation-fade-in-pause-fade-out)

```
  @-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    72% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes fadein {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    72% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  @keyframes fadein {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    72% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }

  }


  @-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    72% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    72% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  @keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    72% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

  }

  .fadeInAndOut{
    -webkit-animation: fadein 1.9s ease-in-out 5s 1,
    fadeOut 1.9s ease-in-out 5s 1 ;
    -moz-animation: fadein 1.9s ease-in-out 5s 1,
    fadeOut 1.9s ease-in-out 5s 1 ;
    animation: fadein 1.9s ease-in-out 5s 1,
    fadeOut 1.9s ease-in-out 5s 1 ;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achive it with one css animation.

```
.el {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.fadeInOut {
    opacity: 0;
   -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 14s;
   animation: fadeInOut 14s;
  }

@keyframes fadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    14% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    86% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
  
    100 {
      opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframe fadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    14% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    86% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
  
    100 {
      opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/callmesupercookie/pen/xxOagdo

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

the number `14` is because we want 2 seconds out of 14

`x = (2*100)/14 = 14.2 =~ 14`

and

`100 - 14 = 86`

so it will fade in for 2sec then appears for 10sec then fade out for 2sec

```css
.fadeInAndOut {
  animation: fadeinout 14s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeinout {

  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  14%, 86% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rs9cbz8g/4/